# Sorting data by Newest and Oldest

Tags: swiftui

I want to sort my custom array by the last tapped(Newest). I can sort by name or by id, but I have trouble sorting by time. I couldn't find similar issues on the internet, and it gives me a lot of headaches. As you can see in my code below, I want to sort the favorite list by the last tapped. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct DataArray: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let cities: String
    let name1: String
    let name2: String
    
    let isFavorite: Bool
    var date = Date()
}

public struct ListDataArray {
    static let dot = [
    DataArray(id: 1,
        cities: "Baltimore"
        name1: "John",
        name2: "Mike",
        isFavorite: False),
        
    DataArray(id: 2,
        cities: "Frederick"),
        name1: "Joe",
        name2: "Swift",
        isFavorite: False),
        
    DataArray(id: 3,
        cities: "Catonsville"
        name1: "Susan",
        name2: "Oliver",
        isFavorite: False),
        
    // There will be a lot of data     
    ]
}

class Prospect: ObservableObject {

    @Published var datas: [DataArray] = []
    
    init() {
        fetchDataArrays()
    }
    
    private func fetchDataArrays() {
        let items = ListDataArray.dot
        datas = items
    }
    
    // To View Favorite
    @Published var showFavorite: Bool = false
}

struct Home: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var items: Prospect
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
        
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(items.datas) { data in
                    
                    VStack {
                        ButtonView(data: data)
                            .environmentObject(items)
                        
                        Text("\(data.id)")
                            .font(.title3)
                        Text(data.cities)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                        Text(data.name1)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                        Text(data.name2)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            
                    }
                    padding()
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var items: Prospect
    let data: DataArray
    
    var index: Int {
        items.datas.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == data.id }) ?? 0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.items.datas[self.index].isFavorite.toggle()
            } label: {
                    
                Image(systemName: self.items.datas[self.index].isFavorite ? "suit.heart.fill" : "suit.heart").padding()
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                items.showFavorite.toggle()
            } label: {
                
                Image(systemName: "person").padding()
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $items.showFavorite) {
                FavoriteView()
                    .environmentObject(items)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct FavoriteView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var items: Prospect
    
    @State var selection = 0
    
    let sortingNames = ["Newest", "Oldest", "A to Z", "Z to A"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        
            HStack {
                ForEach(0...<4) { num in
                    Button(action: {
                        selection = num
                    }, label: {
                        Spacer()
                        Text(sortingNames[num])
                            .forgroundColor(selection == num ? Color.blue: Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    })
                }
            }
        
        
            List {
                ForEach(sorting()) { data in
                    
                    if data.isFavorite {
                    
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            
                            Text(data.cities)
                            Text(data.name1)
                            Text(data.name2)
                            
                        }
                        .font(.body)
                    
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    private func sorting() -> [DataArray] {
        switch selection {
            case 0:
                // Here I want to sort by the Newest...
                return items.datas.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
            case 1:
                // Here I want to sort by the Oldest...
                return items.datas.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
            case 2:
                return items.datas.sorted(by: { $0.cities < $1.cities })
            case 3:
                return items.datas.sorted(by: { $0.cities > $1.cities })
        
        }
    }
}

struct Home_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Home()
            .environmentObject(Prospect())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing **only** on the sorting as per the question, the following works well for me.
The only significant change, was the sort by Oldest. Here is my test code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
 struct DataArray: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let cities: String
    let name1: String
    let name2: String
    
    let isFavorite: Bool
    var date = Date()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let dataArr = [DataArray(id: 1,cities: "Baltimore", name1: "John", name2: "Mike", isFavorite: true,
                             date: Date()),
                   DataArray(id: 2,cities: "Frederick" ,name1: "Joe", name2: "Swift", isFavorite: true,
                             date: .now+1),
                   DataArray(id: 3,cities: "Catonsville", name1: "Susan", name2: "Oliver", isFavorite: true,
                             date: .now+2)
    ]

    @State var selection = 0
    let sortingNames = ["Newest", "Oldest", "A to Z", "Z to A"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                 ForEach(0..<4) { num in
                     Button(action: { selection = num}) {
                         Text(sortingNames[num])
                             .foregroundColor(selection == num ? Color.blue: Color.black)
                     }
                 }
             }
            List {
                ForEach(sorting()) { data in
                    if data.isFavorite {
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Text("\(data.id)").foregroundColor(.red) // <-- for testing
                            Text(data.cities)
                            Text(data.name1)
                            Text(data.name2)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sorting() -> [DataArray] {
        switch selection {
        case 0:
            // Here I want to sort by the Newest...
            return dataArr.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
        case 1:
            // Here I want to sort by the Oldest...
            return dataArr.sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date }) // <--- here
        case 2:
            return dataArr.sorted(by: { $0.cities < $1.cities })
        case 3:
            return dataArr.sorted(by: { $0.cities > $1.cities })
        default:
            return dataArr   // <--- here need a default
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT1:

Since I don't know what you really want to do with your app,
I just modified your (test) code to show you an approach for getting your data sorted.

The main emphasis here is to have
one source of truth of the data, starting in `ContenView` `@StateObject var items = Prospect()`.
Also made `sorting()` sorting the data `in-place`, so that it appear sorted everywhere.
Moved `sorting()` into your `Prospect` model.

I also renamed the badly named `DataArray` to `CityData`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var items = Prospect()
    
    var body: some View {
        Home().environmentObject(items)
    }
}

struct Home: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var items: Prospect
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(items.datas) { data in
                    VStack {
                        ButtonView(data: data)
                        Text("\(data.id)").font(.title3)
                        Text(data.cities).font(.subheadline)
                        Text(data.name1).font(.subheadline)
                        Text(data.name2).font(.subheadline)
                    }.padding()
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var items: Prospect
    @State var data: CityData  // <--- here
    @State var index: Int = 0  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: { items.datas[index].isFavorite.toggle() }) {
                Image(systemName: items.datas[index].isFavorite ? "suit.heart.fill" : "suit.heart").padding()
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: { items.showFavorite.toggle() }) {
                Image(systemName: "person").padding()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            if let ndx = items.datas.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == data.id }) {
                index = ndx
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $items.showFavorite) {
            FavoriteView().environmentObject(items)
        }
    }
}

struct FavoriteView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @EnvironmentObject var items: Prospect

    @State var selection = 0
    let sortingNames = ["Newest", "Oldest", "A to Z", "Z to A"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {dismiss()}) {
                Text("Done").foregroundColor(.blue) // <-- for testing on macos
            }
            HStack {
                 ForEach(0..<4) { num in
                     Button(action: {
                         selection = num
                         items.sorting(selection)   // <--- here
                     }) {
                         Text(sortingNames[num])
                             .foregroundColor(selection == num ? Color.blue: Color.black)
                     }
                 }
             }
            List {
                ForEach(items.datas) { data in  // <--- here
                    if data.isFavorite {
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            Text("\(data.id)").foregroundColor(.red) // <-- for testing
                            Text(data.cities)
                            Text(data.name1)
                            Text(data.name2)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

class Prospect: ObservableObject {
    @Published var datas: [CityData] = []
    @Published var showFavorite: Bool = false
    
    init() {
        fetchCityDatas()
    }
    
    private func fetchCityDatas() {
        datas = ListCityData.dot
    }
    
    // --- sort in place note sort() not sorted() ---
    func sorting(_ selection: Int) {
        switch selection {
        case 0:
            // Here I want to sort by the Newest...
            datas.sort(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
        case 1:
            // Here I want to sort by the Oldest...
            datas.sort(by: { $0.date > $1.date }) // <--- here
        case 2:
            datas.sort(by: { $0.cities < $1.cities })
        case 3:
            datas.sort(by: { $0.cities > $1.cities })
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

public struct ListCityData {
    static let dot = [CityData(id: 1,cities: "Baltimore", name1: "John", name2: "Mike", isFavorite: true,
                                date: .now),
                      CityData(id: 2,cities: "Frederick" ,name1: "Joe", name2: "Swift", isFavorite: true,
                                date: .now+10),
                      CityData(id: 3,cities: "Catonsville", name1: "Susan", name2: "Oliver", isFavorite: true,
                                date: .now+20)
       ]
}

// --- here renamed and using var ---
struct CityData: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var cities: String
    var name1: String
    var name2: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var date: Date
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply @workingdog. Mine still doesn't work and I don't know why. By the way, the [DataArray] will be a lot in my case. So, I cannot put like let dataArr = [....]. Will it be the reason that mine is not working?

Comment: updated my answer with another approach to sorting your data.

Comment: Thanks again @workingdog. Now, I can see clearly, and it is very straightforward when you guide me with your commands.